# Hom(-,N) is left exact if $N \in \mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ is semi simple and indecomposable

Tags: category-theory, exact-sequence

I have the following situation: 
$\mathcal{M}$ is a semi simple, indecomposable module category over a semisimple, rigid monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$ with finitely many irreducible objects and irreducible unit object. Let $N$ be an object in $\mathcal{M}$.

In my exercise it says that $\mathrm{Hom}(-, N)$ is left exact under those conditions. 
Why is that?

Comment: What is a semisimple, indecomposable category? Do you mean that $N$ is semisimple and indecomposable? Since $N$ is semisimple then its every submodule is a direct summand. So $N$ is simple because it is indecomposable.

Comment: I asked myself the same thing, but I think the definitions consider two different things: The semi simplicity of the category means, that every object can be written as a direct sum of simple objects, while for the category to be indecomposable means that the category itself can't be written as a direct sum of two non-trivial categories.

Comment: I am not sure anymore... maybe you are right...

Comment: Wow, I've never heard about the concept of indecomposable category. Do you have some reference so I could learn more about it?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111139 Definition 7

Comment: @freakish lets say that $N$ is simple. Does it then follow that $\mathrm{Hom}(-, N)$ is left exact?

Comment: My mistake, the $\text{Hom}(N,-)$ is exact which easily follows from $N$ being simple. But I don't think that $\text{Hom}(-,N)$ needs to be in general. But let me ask this: so $\mathcal{M}$ is a (full?) subcategory of $\text{Mod}(R)$ for some ring $R$? Such that all objects in $\mathcal{M}$ are semisimple (even though $R$ does not have to be) and $\mathcal{M}$ is indecomposable? That sounds to weak. Or is $\mathcal{M}$ just $\text{Mod}(R)$ in which case $R$ has to be semisimple.

Comment: Maybe I should write that more explicitly in the question, let me edit it. @freakish is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent characterization of $\mathcal{M}$ being semisimple is that every $N\in \mathcal{M}$ is injective (see e.g. [R is semisimple if and only if every R module is projective](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2755769/15416) for the dual statement). $\operatorname{Hom}(-,N)$ being exact is equivalent to $N$ being injective.

Comment: thanks! do you have any reference? Maybe one where explicitly categories are used? I didn't finde anything categorical, just modules.

Comment: @Polly What definition of semisimple are you using? (another related stackexchange question is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2055190/15416 )

Comment: In the paper I am working in no definition is given. I always worked with this one: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semisimple+abelian+category